# When some program crashes, how can I send the feedback to myself?

Tags: crash-reports

When a program crashes, I can view the crash info by clicking on send feedback, then preview. However it is sometimes quite inconvenient to go through the error log on the phone and I would instead prefer to view it on my computer. How can I email the feedback to myself, or in some other way view the error log on my computer?

[image]

I use Android 10 on unrooted Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: The common way would be to connect the device via USB, enable ADB and then execute `adb logcat` which should hopefully show the error if the adb log has not yet overwritten it with new messages.

Comment: @Robert thanks, bummer, amazing that there's no way for the user to have a convenient access to the log

Comment: May be Google did not had us 0.01% of all Android users in mind that are capable of interpreting an Android app crash log/stack trace ;)

Comment: @Robert true but allowing the user to copy paste the error log that they can view in the preview doesn't seem to require that much coding resources :/